# What does "Have fun with 'em homies" mean?

Tags: meaning

I come across these sorts of sentences frequently. I'd like to give more examples to be more precise.

> Kill 'em homies.
>
> Look at 'em idiots.

What do they really mean?  I mean why add *them* in front of a plural noun? And is this an informal way of speaking?

Comment: It's dialectical. If it makes you feel better, you can mentally substitute "those" for "them" (and "them" for "'em").

Comment: I'm British, and I often hear/use ***them*** instead of ***those***, but in my experience hardly anyone ever drops the initial "th" in that usage (despite the fact that we regularly do this when using ***them*** in other contexts). I'm not so sure whether Americans are the same in this respect (but they're much more likely to render ***them*** as ***dem*** anyway, so things are already different).

Comment: @FumbleFingers, even us Chicagoans don't replace "them" with "dem", except in Saturday Night Live skits and if you're a gangster! (Rolling eyes) lol!

Comment: You should also consider that your first example could well be, and your second example might possibly be, a simple omittted comma, changing the sense entirely. "Fight fiercely, Harvard", as Tom Lehrer sang.

Comment: [ABCD goldfish? LMNO goldfish. OSAR goldfish. ICM!](https://www.englishforums.com/English/CanSomeoneChildrensRhyme/bmpmb/post.htm) (dat's two **'em=them** and one **'ey=they**).